# Order-Preserving Bijection $f:A\to A^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, category-theory, order-theory

Let $A$ be a well-quasi-ordered infnite set. Does there exist an order-preserving bijection $f:A\to A^*$, where $A^*$ is the free monoid over $A$ under the subword ordering? Would this subword ordering make $A^*$ well-quasi-ordered as well (reference to Corollary $1.7$ of [2]).

References:

1. http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/155notes/lecture19.pdf
2. https://research-repository.st-andrews.ac.uk/bitstream/10023/7963/1/BCCpaperv9.pdf
3. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.5070v2.pdf

---

Crossposted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230143/order-perserving-bijection-fa-to-a).

Discussion: https://mathoverflow.net/a/230193/82691

Comment: certainly not for finite $A$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Why? Then how about infinite $A$?

Comment: The set of words on A is always infinite, so if A is finite there is no hope for a bijection.

Comment: The free monoid on a nonempty set is always infinite.

Comment: @Pedro Right. I just missed the obvious. :/

Comment: @MattSamuel I knew that at the least.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If you could, I would be happy to see your attempt. Or unless someone else could do so...